# Getting HTTP status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect: using curl to post/put json request

Tags: json, spring, curl

I am working with spring MVC with both xml/json objects and I am getting following error:

```
HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().
```

This is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/emp")
public @ResponseBody EmployeeList addEmp(@RequestBody Employee e) {
    employeeDS.add(e);
    List<Employee> employees = employeeDS.getAll();
    EmployeeList list = new EmployeeList(employees);
    return list;
}


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/emp/{id}")
public @ResponseBody EmployeeList updateEmp(@RequestBody Employee e, @PathVariable String id) {
    employeeDS.update(e);
    List<Employee> employees = employeeDS.getAll();
    EmployeeList list = new EmployeeList(employees);
    return list;
}
```

I am trying to send JSON object using curl:

```
curl -v -X PUT -HContent-type:application/json --data '{"id":3,"name":"guest","email":"guest@ibm.com"}' http://localhost:8080/rest/service/emp/1


curl -v -X POST -HContent-type:application/json --data '{"id":3,"name":"guest","email":"guest@ibm.com"}' http://localhost:8080/rest/service/emp
```

I have added following jackson dependencies in pom file:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have also added following configuration in my servlet-dispatcher.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />

            <!--entry key="html" value="text/html"/-->

        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <!-- JSON View -->
      <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
      </bean>

      <!-- JAXB XML View -->
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
               <property name="classesToBeBound">
                <list>
                   <value>com.mkyong.common.bean.Employee</value>
                   <value>com.mkyong.common.bean.EmployeeList</value>
                </list>
               </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
     </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />

    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="order" value="2" />
                <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingConverter" />
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="marshallingConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller" />       
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
```

Here is how the Employee class looks like:

```
package com.mkyong.common.bean;
```

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="employee")
public class Employee {

```
private long id;
private String name;
private String email;

public Employee() {}

public Employee(long id, String name, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

I have the following jars in my lib:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.5.3.jar
aspectjweaver-1.5.3.jar
axiom-api-1.2.7.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.12.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.jar
joda-time-1.6.2.jar
opensaml-2.5.1-1.jar
openws-1.4.2-1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-security-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-xml-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar
wss4j-1.6.5.jar
xmlsec-1.5.1.jar
xmlsec-2.0.jar
xmltooling-1.3.2-1.jar
xws-security-1.3.1.jar
```

My GET works just fine for both XML and JSON:

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/emp/{id}", headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
public @ResponseBody Employee getEmp(@PathVariable String id) {
    Employee e = employeeDS.get(Long.parseLong(id));
    return e;
}
```

for following curl command:

```
curl -HAccept:application/xml  http://localhost:8080/rest/service/emp/1
curl -HAccept:application/json  http://localhost:8080/rest/service/emp/1
```

Comment: Can you please show us what your `Employee` class looks like?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - i have added below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have actually created your project. Using eclipse in windows on tomcat. I used spring 3.2.4 (but I don't think it makes a difference).

I encountered the same problem as you when I sent it incorrect json so I think it is your curl command which is wrong. Are you on windows? If so you must escape your quotes. I sent it the following:

```
C:\> curl -v -X POST -HContent-type:application/json -d "{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"guest\",\"email\":\"guest@ibm.com\"}" http://localhost:8080/HelperSpringMVC/emp
* Adding handle: conn: 0x6a3400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x6a3400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /HelperSpringMVC/emp HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-type:application/json
> Content-Length: 47
>
* upload completely sent off: 47 out of 47 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 11 Sep 2013 21:07:47 GMT
<
[{"id":10,"name":"john","email":"email"},{"id":3,"name":"guest","email":"guest@ibm.com"}]
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Note my controller is a bit different it is here:

```
@Controller
public class controller {
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/emp")
public @ResponseBody List<Employee> addEmp(@RequestBody Employee e, BindingResult results) {
    if (results.hasErrors()) {
        return new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    list.add(new Employee(10, "john", "email"));
    list.add(e);
    return list;
}
....
```

Shout if this doesn't help or you want any of my files.

Comment: You are right. It worked by escaping quotes. Your curl command gave me xml response. I have to add -HAccept:application/json in the curl request to get json response.

Comment: I had the similar error and found that I set a field to string which should be a number. After I correct it, the post became successful. :)

Comment: @john I have implemented this above code.I am using Spring MVC 4.0. It is showing bad request 400. have any idea

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error when I posted to a normal http controller. My problem happened when the binding failed, the solution was that I needed to include BindingResult result. You could try adding that after your model for POST.

Comment: I have added BindingResult in the method. Looks like it does not even go to the controller

Comment: If you're using beans and mappers, you need to have fields on your bean that can accept the data type provided from the UI as well as on read, from the backend RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's the syntax of curl, but my curl command is as follow and works for me (your -H option part is different from mine)

`curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"id":123, "name":"User123"}' http://localhost:8080/restful/user`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how Employee class look like

```
package com.mkyong.common.bean;
```

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="employee")
public class Employee {

```
private long id;
private String name;
private String email;

public Employee() {}

public Employee(long id, String name, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

Comment: There's an `edit` button under your question. You don't need to post an answer, just add the code to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my controller method after adding BindingResult

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/emp/{id}")
public @ResponseBody EmployeeList updateEmp(@RequestBody Employee e, @PathVariable String id, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("Error ::: " +result.toString());
    }
    employeeDS.update(e);
    List<Employee> employees = employeeDS.getAll();
    EmployeeList list = new EmployeeList(employees);
    return list;
}
```