# How to deserialize json to a complicated object by using spring mvc?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

Let's say i have posted JSON to server as following:

```
{
    warFile: {name: "test1", dependencies: [test0, test2]},
    param: {build: true, test: true}
}
```

And i have 3 classes as following:

```
public class WarFile{
   private String name:
   private String[] dependencies;
   public void setName(){...};
   public String getName(){...};
   public void setDependencies(){...};
   public String[] getDependencies(){...};
}

public class Param{
   private boolean build;
   private boolean test;
   public void setBuild(){...};
   public boolean isBuild(){...};
   public void setTest(){...};
   public boolean isTest(){...};
}

public class Command{
    private WarFile warFile;
    private Param param;
    private void setWarFile(){...};
    private WarFile getWarFile(){...};
    private void setParam(){...};
    private Param getParam(){...};
}
```

Controller as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test.ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
BuildResult buildWar(@RequestBody Command cmd) {
    return logic.build(cmd.getWarFile(), cmd.getParam());
}
```

And since `warFile` and `param` in Command are not a primitive type, I always get the following error:

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

I'm sure that there is not any problem if all the properties in Command are primitive type. But how comes this error happened? I mean, the objects are simple, no need to write a custom deserializer for them.

Comment: Please show the code of how you are posting the JSON content to the server.  Also, do you have Jackson on your classpath?  What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: The post part works correctly for other request, and i do imported Jackson. The thing is i got error when i want to deserialize a complicated Object. If the object only contains properties which are int, string, list... no any problem. the process works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The request sent to the client was syntactically incorrect" means there is something wrong with the content of the request you sent, not necessarily your controller or Spring configuration. First off, your JSON is not valid. Jackson can't properly map the JSON to the objects it should represent. It should be:

```
{
    "warFile": {
        "name": "test1",
        "dependencies": ["test0", "test2"]
    },
    "param": {
        "build": true,
        "test": true
    }
}
```

Second, make sure the content type is application/json. Lastly, why does your Command object have private getters/setters, and your setters don't have field parameters?

Comment: private getters/sertters are mistake when i am writing this issue. Thank you for correcting this.

Answer (score 0):

Is your request mapping is /test.ajax or /test in your html `<form>`?

Have you added jackson mapper jar dependency ? if yes next solution would be escape your quotes i guess. this might help
[Spring MVC : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990717/spring-mvc-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect)

[Getting HTTP status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect: using curl to post/put json request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705497/getting-http-status-400-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incor)

Comment: I added Jackson as dependency. The problem is that i got error only if the Command contains other objects as properties. If the properties in Command are only some primitive type, like int, boolean, string... it works fine.