# HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect content type, Form Select

Tags: jquery, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

I don't know really why it doesn't work.

I have the following error

```
HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report

message

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

webpage

```
<%@page language="Java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.button').click(function() {
        var val = $('#myForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'post-add',
            type: 'POST',
            data : val,
            success: function(s) {
                alert('goodjob');
            }
        });        
    });

});
</script>

<button class="button" value="add">add</button>

<form:form modelAttribute="objectAttribute" id="myForm">
       <form:input path="title"/>
       <form:select path="client">
            <c:forEach items="${clients}" var="item">
                    <form:option value="${item.id}" label="${item.name}"/>
            </c:forEach>    
        </form:select>
</form:form>
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "post-add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addObject(
            @ModelAttribute("objectAttribute") MyObject myObject) {

        objectService.insert(myObject);

        return "redirect: list";
    }
```

I've come to one conclusion, when I remove the select option the Controller tries to save the object (unfortunately without the client will not do).

If I'll leave the select, then I get this error HTTP Status 400.

Any ideas? Why it happens...

Edit: From FireBug Console

```
Parameters application/x-www-form-urlencoded
title   a
client  1
_csrf   1b1d2b07-937f-4066-b7a0-718673351b26

Source
title=a&client=1&_csrf=1b1d2b07-937f-4066-b7a0-718673351b26
```

UPDATE

Ok, what I did:

Client Entity

From

```
private long id;
public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

to

```
private String id;
public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Now it works!! Why?

Comment: Could you add the value of `val` to your question? Would help to see what is actually sent to the controller.

Comment: why you are calling ajax?Just post the form

Comment: can you post the actual HTML output of the form

Comment: I also learn Ajax, so trying to use it as much as possible. In addition, this form once worked...

Comment: here you want to sand data from ajax or from form?

Comment: check out what I wrote in the above-UPDATE

Comment: @user2363971 have you tried replacing `modelAttribute` with `commandName`

Comment: @ankur-singhal Yeah and it doesnt work. So I am weird and I do workaround. Simply to my Controller I added BindingResult (at now Controller receive some data, everything except the client) and @RequestParam("client") Long clientid. At the end of using the clientid i just download client object in Controller and assign to my object from Form. So happy...

Comment: @user2363971 Good you got it running somehow, have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705497/getting-http-status-400-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incor). It talks just about the sam eproble, sending json data and all, same exception, let me know if it helps.